# select random images from MNIST dataset

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

first of all, I must admit that I have limited experience with python and TensorFlow. I am looking for some support about the manipulation of the MNIST images imported from the TensorFlow examples.

What I want to is the following:

1. import the MNIST dataset from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist
2. store half randomly selected pictures from MNIST in an array such that I can manipulate it

The code that I am writing is the following

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/MNIST/',one_hot=True)
import random

rndm_imgs = random.sample(data.test.images, len(data.test.images)/2)
```

I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 320, in sample
    raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

Anyone who can support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good habit when using python is to run your programs with `python -i program.py`, so that you can use the shell to interactively inspect what each of your variables hold. If you print `data.test.images`, you'll see that it is an n-darray (n-dimensional numpy array) of shape (10000, 784). So basically it is a matrix where each row is an image (mnist is 28x28 hence 784).

If you want to use python's inbuilt random.sample function to sample, convert the data matrix into a list such that each element is an image (a vector of 784 dimensions or elements).

```
data_test_list = list(data.test.images)
test_samples = random.samples(data_test_list, len(data.test.images)/2)
test_samples = np.array(test_samples)
```

Notice that after getting our samples, we are casting the result back into a numpy array because that's generally what you want to be dealing with in the context of tensorflow.